# Serialize an object into a string

Tags: java

Can someone help me to serialze an object into a string? The result of my code is a bit weird, I need to get a toString(); methode or something with which i can serialze an object into a string but I dont know any.

Thanks for the help

results with getString -> only "null"

result without getString(); -> Fruit@4dd8dc3,      Fruit@6d03e736, Fruit@568db2f2, Fruit@378bf509, Fruit@5fd0d5ae,
Fruit@2d98a335, Fruit@16b98e56, Fruit@7ef20235"

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit>,Serializable{

    String getString;
    String name;
    int gewicht;

    public String getString() {

            return this.getString;

          }

    public Fruit(String name, int gewicht) {
        this.name=name;
        this.gewicht=gewicht;
    }

    public int compareTo(Fruit otherFruit) {

        if(this.gewicht < otherFruit.gewicht)
            return -1;
        if(this.gewicht>otherFruit.gewicht)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }


}




import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class FruitTree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TreeSet<Fruit> fruitTree = new TreeSet<Fruit>();

        fruitTree.add(new Fruit("Kiwi",5));
        fruitTree.add(new Fruit("Kirsche",1));
        fruitTree.add(new Fruit("Ananas",75));
        fruitTree.add(new Fruit("Zitrone",15));
        fruitTree.add(new Fruit("Grapefruit",44));
        fruitTree.add(new Fruit("Banane",55));
        fruitTree.add(new Fruit("Kirsche",2));
        fruitTree.add(new Fruit("Kiwi",8));

        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("IO.txt"));
            Iterator<Fruit> it = fruitTree.iterator();



            while(it.hasNext()) {
            oos.writeObject(it.next());
        }
            oos.writeObject(null);



            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream (new FileInputStream("IO.txt"));

            Object readObject=null;
            TreeSet<Fruit> deserializedFruits= new TreeSet<Fruit>();

            do {
                readObject=ois.readObject();
                if(readObject !=null)
                    deserializedFruits.add((Fruit) readObject);
            }
            while (readObject!=null);

            it=deserializedFruits.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(it.next().getString());
                ois.close();
                oos.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        }




    }
```

Can someone help me to serialze an object into a string? The result of my code is a bit weird, I need to get a toString(); methode or something with which i can serialze an object into a string but I dont know any.

Thanks for the help

Comment: `getString()` would work if you had put some value into `getString` (what a terrible name for a field)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `implements Serializable` to your class will not override default `Object.toString` implementation - that's not how Java works (btw this default implementation will actually provide you what you got - for example `Fruit@5fd0d5ae` - that's how it works)

what you need to do is to override `toString` by yourself - for example

```
public class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit>,Serializable {
    // ...

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name: " + this.name + ", gewicht: " + String.valueOf(this.gewicht);
    }
}
```

or to use some existing tool that will generate this method for you (like [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)), or even better that will allow you to serialize your class object to some common format like *JSON* or XML (for this take a look at [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson))